# All navigation fails and leads me to homepage

Tags: navigation

I installed a plug-in and then uninstalled and deleted it (wp e-commerce).

Now all links lead me back to homepage. When I click on a post heading I go to homepage.

I do not have caching.

I tried moving to another theme and then back to mine.

Please help..

Comment: Is navigation worked when switched to different theme, please add all your findings to this question. coz, its not answerable by given data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more information is welcome.

maybe your .htaccess file got messed up?
Delete it and, recreate in settings permalinks.

1. deleting .htaccess.
   use your prefered ftp client and go into your root folder.
   find a file called .htaccess and delete it. If you can not seem to locate it make sure your settings show 'hidden' files. .htaccess is a hidden file. 
   [image]
2. recreating .htaccess 
   go to settings > permalinks

   [image: permalinks]
3. Next , save your settings as wanted.
   [image]

or if you are not sure before you do post it here.

Comment: Thanks. I changed permalinks to post-number and then back to the original setting and it works now OK.

Comment: ok great, good thing it got fixed. 
Remember when you got problems where you end up somewhere you shouldn't be , check the .htaccess file first , or recreate it.